# Term to summarize webpage and mobile app

Tags: terminology

I am currently making a UX design course, so I am sorry if my question is silly.

I am starting with my first projects and this question that I´ve been asking to myself for a while, is now stuck in my head. Is there a (single) term to summarize webpage and mobile app? I feel that for usability tests and surveys, it will be easier to get users straighter thoughts with one term.

I know I could say web/mobile app. But most users seem to relate ¨app¨ with mobile products only.

Comment: This used to be the case, but the trend is moving towards development frameworks that allow you to design and then deploy onto multiple platforms (i.e. browser and native applications). So if you use the term application then it is a catch-all web or mobile applications unless you specify the exact context.

Answer (score 1):

You're working on a usability script right? If you're looking for a term to use in conversation with a user, use terms they're familiar with. Apps to 'regular folk' means something you install on your phone. Websites are... well websites. I don't think web app is a known enough term to use in a test environment, so I'd avoid that.

It's easiest to just use terms that are understood best in a particular situation. A user will not care/notice that it's not technically correct, they mostly seek clarity above all. They care how they experience the product, not how it performs behind the scenes.